# Cannot open or create file set by xcache.mmap_path

Tags: php, cpanel, xcache

I'm getting the following error on my server with xcache...

`Cannot open or create file set by xcache.mmap_path, check the path permission or check xcache.size/var_size against system limitation`

my php.ini is as follows:

```
xcache.size="64M"
xcache.var_size="64M"
xcache.mmap_path="/tmp/xcache/"
```

I used to have them much higher but have lowered them for testing. I also tried lowering them to 4M but that still throws the same error.

the /tmp mount is 8% full and when I run df -i, it's only at 1% usage

xcache has been working fine for years but my cPanel server just ran some automatic updates tonight and obviously messed something up. can't seem to find a solution and cPanel doesn't know what's wrong.

Comment: whats the files\path permission?

Comment: /tmp is drwxrwxrwt. The xcache directory should be created when apache is started.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer might not directly help you, I had the same problem and was able to fix it by deleting the `/xcache/` folder.  I had changed my mmap location from `/dev/zero` to `/tmp/xcache` and had created an xcache folder.

as soon as I deleted the folder, it started working properly.  I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

use file path instead of directory: xcache.mmap_path="/tmp/xcache" and yes rmdir /tmp/xcache/ if it exists as file or rm /tmp/xcache as file before you restart php+xcache